# How to evaluate command in Next.js .env file?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I have the following .env.development file:

```
IP="$(ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet /{print $2}')"
GQL_HOST_HTTP="http://$IP:3030/graphql"
```

The expectation is that `GQL_HOST_HTTP` ends up as `"http://192.169.0.1:3030/graphql"` (depending on my local machine IP, as should be retrived by the command under the `$IP` variable).

However, the `$IP` variable gets evaluated as a string, so `GQL_HOST_HTTP` ends up as `http://(ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet /{print '):3030/graphql` (the `$2`) part of `IP` gets interpreted as a variable, unfortunately).

How do I evaluate the `$IP` variable? I tried storing the ip as a local system environment variable referencing local environemnt variable, but next.js does not seem to have access to those.